# ReactJS: Проверка кук

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

Делаю приложения используя сервер написанный на NodeJS&ExpressJS и веб клиент на ReactJS. Имеется авторизация пользователя с куками, куки формируются на сервере с помощью "express-session"

```
req.session.UUID = member.userUUID; 
req.session.UserName= member.userName;
```

Как проверить существуют ли эти поля (или сами нужные куки) в ReactJS приложение и допустим поменять какую-то часть сайта в зависимости от того, авторизован пользователь или нет.
Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 0):

`if(req.session.UUID && req.session.username) {/*код изменения элементов которые нужны, на счёт реакта хз но вот к примеру в обычном хтмл это - */ document.getElementById('usernameLabel').innerText = req.session.username}`